# How to prevent Viewstate tampering in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, security, viewstate

This is an Interview Question I was asked today -_-. I dont understand the question actually, because I dont understand how anything can be tampered in the scenario. He asked this when I was talking about using AJAX with $http.

Comment: 1 : did you asked him what kind of tampering..? 2: at which place 3 : any scenario

Answer (score 0):

Let me divide the question

0 : Prevent 1 : viewstate 2 : tempering 3 : in angularjs

`Viewstate tampering in AngularJS :`

Might be a normal customer action (form or `view`) in angularjs

where user tries to ( `temper` or change or edit) the form

and now how will `we` come to know the (state or change) of (form or view or `viewstate`)has changed

Now here comes `dirty tracking concept` .

In Angular there are couple of ways for that.

So for (`Preventing` or `knowing` the changes we can use) `$digest` or `$watch` in angular

And

`$http : dosen't knows any thing about dirty tracking he just sends or brings data`